# Unknown column 'a1.location' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql

Im trying to execute this query

```
UPDATE airport AS a1, 
(SELECT location_ar 
FROM airport as a3 
WHERE a3.location = a1.location AND a3.location_ar != NULL LIMIT 1) as a2 
SET a1.location_ar = a2.location_ar WHERE a1.location = NULL;
```

But im getting "Unknown column 'a1.location' in 'where clause'",

Edited: the new query is:

```
UPDATE airport AS a1, (SELECT location_ar FROM airport WHERE location = a1.location AND a3.location_ar != NULL LIMIT 1) as a2 SET a1.location_ar = a2.location_ar WHERE a1.location = NULL;
```

Help please

Comment: you are trying to set two alias for same table?

Comment: Try airport.location, does this work?

Comment: airport.location doesn't work,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to do it would be using join

```
update airport a1
join airport a2 on a1.location = a2.location and a2.location_ar is not NULL
set a1.location_ar = a2.location_ar
where a1.location is NULL;
```

Comment: last line was where a1.location_ar is NULL; 

Thanks it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
UPDATE airport AS a1, 
(SELECT location_ar FROM airport as a3 
 WHERE a3.location = airport.location 
 AND a3.location_ar is not NULL LIMIT 1) as a2 
 SET a1.location_ar = a2.location_ar 
 WHERE a1.location is NULL;
```

Comment: Unknown column 'airport.location' in 'where clause'